# Is it possible to slipstream updates?

Tags: updates

With Windows you can take a pre-existing image, and slip stream service packs/updates/patches, so you don't have to install thousands of updates after you install Windows.

Does Ubuntu have that option, if so how would one do that?
Is there a more to update image then the official current release?

I have noticed that after you install the final release of an Ubuntu release, there are tons of updates, depending on how long that release has been out, it sometimes numbers around 500 updates or so. For some people this is unacceptable especially if you are doing a large roll out, the last thing you want to do is install 500 updates on say... 30 machines for example.

Any thoughts or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Download the Daily Build which is updated everyday and contains all the updates to the os till date.

[Lucid Daily Build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lucid/daily-live/current/)

[Natty Daily Build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/)